# German 81a AufenthG skilled residence permit (family reunion)

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, immigration, resident-permit

I have a job offer from a German employer and they are initiating the 81a accelerated visa process for me since normal work visa takes a lot of time.

I am from Pakistan and comes under the Islamabad Embassy to submit my documents here in Pakistan.

My employer has submitted documents for my family (wife and daughter) along with me to get the pre-approval.

My question now is: will my family get their family visa along with me or not?

PS: In normal work visa category for Germany from Pakistan the family get their visa after a long time.

Comment: Can you please update how did the process go?